# Rotating objects using multitouch

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

I am new to andengine and even android game development. i have created sprite as a box. this box is now draggable by using this coding. it works fine.

but i want multitouch on this which i want to rotate a sprite with 2 finger in that box and even it should be draggable. .... plz help someone...

i am trying this many days but no idea.

```
   final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mBox.getWidth()) / 2;

   final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mBox.getHeight()) / 2;
     Box= new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mBox,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

     public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
           this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth()/ 2,
                           pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);

             float pValueX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
            float pValueY = CAMERA_HEIGHT-pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

            float  dx = pValueX -  gun.getX();
            float  dy = pValueY -  gun.getY();

             double  Radius = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
             double Angle = Radius * 360 ;

                Box.setRotation((float)Math.toDegrees(Angle));
                 return true;
        }
```

Comment: Plz can anyone clarify this doubt. It is important for all android people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enabled multi touch in your game. You can use the same code used in the [MultiTouchExample](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/MultiTouchExample.java) in the `onLoadEngine` method.

The algorithm is quite simple, similar to what you've posted here.

1. Keep track of up to 2 pointer IDs you get in `onAreaTouched` method. (You can get the pointer ID by calling `pSceneTouchEvent.getPointerID()`).
2. Keep track of the pointers' state (Currently touching/not touching) and location (`pTouchAreaLocalX` and `pTouchAreaLocalY`).
3. Whenever 2 pointers are touching (You received `ACTION_DOWN` for both), save the initial angle. (`Math.tan2(pointer1Y - pointer2Y, pointer1X - pointer2X)`).
4. As long as `ACTION_UP` is not called for the pointers, update the new angle in every `ACTION_MOVE` event of the pointers, and get the angle delta (`delta = currentAngle - initialAngle`). Then call `setRotation(Math.toDegrees(delta))`.

To make the sprite dragable with 2 pointers, you need to move your sprite the lesser of the distance each pointer has moved. For example, if:

```
pointer1.dX = 50;
pointer1.dY = -20;
pointer2.dX = 40;
pointer2.dY = -10;
```

the sprite should move +40 units in the X axis, and -10 units in the Y axis.

Comment: Can u provide the code for it? i do not understand how to get two pointer ids? when i touch with two fingers and count them by pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent.getCount(); so it gives 1. If i write pSceneTouchEvent.getPointerID()); then it gives 1st pointer id, how to get second?

Comment: I looked in the code of `MultiTouchController.java`, and AndEngine fires a `TouchEvent` for each pointer in the `MotionEvent`, so you should be getting 2 calls to your touch event method.

Comment: Can someone post how to do thing i mean it kind of get it